# How to combine two arrays for a specific index without concatenation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays that I want to merge to a new one but I need to insert the indices in specific places

```
array1 = np.arange(95,320,4)
array2 = np.arange(0,360,2)
```

For example.. `array1[0] = 95`, but I want this value to be in a new array between `array2[47]` which equals 94 and `array2[48]` that equals 96, and so on with the rest of the values inside array1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Python language?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a general "question & answer platform" for multiple programming languages, so please add a tag to your question for the programming language you use in your question. This will also notify people who have experience with that language.

Comment: Can you give an example with a smaller array?  It sounds like you want a nested array rather than a continuous one, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: `np.insert(array2, np.searchsorted(array2, array1), array1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're looking for [numpy.insert](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)

```py
array1 = np.arange(95,320,4)
array2 = np.arange(0,360,2)

for i, value in enumerate(array1):
  index = i+48+i*2
  array2 = np.insert(array2, index, array1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want exactly, but it might be the following:

So you have two arrays (`arr1` and `arr2`):

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(95, 320, 4)
arr2 = np.arange(0, 360, 2)
```

And you have two lists of indexes (`idxs1` and `idxs2`) mapping between those arrays' elements and their index in the merged array:

```py
n1, n2 = len(arr1), len(arr2)
n = n1 + n2

idxs = np.arange(n)

rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.shuffle(idxs)

idxs1 = idxs[:n1]
idxs2 = idxs[n1:]
```

Then you can construct the merged array pretty easily as so:

```py
merged = np.empty(n)
merged[idxs1] = arr1
merged[idxs2] = arr2
```

Let's check the properties I assumed you want to achieved:

```py
for i in range(n1):
    assert merged[idxs1[i]] == arr1[i]

for i in range(n2):
    assert merged[idxs2[i]] == arr2[i]
```